# i want negative and postive value two number after decimal in texinput format

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d{0,2}')),
```

this flitering texinput only allow number and decimal value (eg,1.22) but i want (-1.22)

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[-0-9]")),
```

but this allow negative and postive value but i cannot deny decimaly more than two value after the point

Answer (score 1):

You can add escaped "-" in front

```
RegExp(r'^\-\d+\.?\d{0,2}')
```

And if you want to match negative and positive numbers use

```
RegExp(r'^\-?\d+\.?\d{0,2}')
```

? will make regex match between 0 or 1 occurrence of "-"

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-*` like this :

```
RegExp(r'^\-*\d+\.?\d{0,2}')
```

You can take a reference from here [GFG RegExp](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-regular-expressions/)

Comment: Adding * would also match positive numbers, OP said to match negative.

Comment: Oh yeah! True..